# MFC ComboBox: Not Displaying Text Box

Tags: c++, combobox, mfc, toolbar

So in my mainframe function I have created a toolbar, and on this tool bar I want to include 2 standard combo boxes: (text box, drop down button, drop down menu). I use the CComboBox class. My Toolbars are also created using CBCGPro.

The first combobox is created and looks fine. Here is the code:

```
CRect rect;

m_wndToolBarSelectCN.SetButtonInfo(0, IDM_SHOW_SELECT_CN_TOOLBAR, TBBS_SEPARATOR, 175);  
m_wndToolBarSelectCN.GetItemRect(0, &rect);
rect.bottom = rect.top + 200;

sg_cbToolsbarClasses.Create(WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|WS_VSCROLL|CBS_DROPDOWN, rect,
                            &m_wndToolBarSelectCN, IDS_TOOLBAR_SELECT_CB_CLASS);
```

m_wndToolBarSelectCN is the toolbar I created in my mainframe function, and sg_cbToolsbarClasses is my CcomboBox objct.

My second ComboBox directly to the right of the first one, has the dropdown menu and the dropdown button but not the textbox. Also all of its functionalities work. Here is the code:

```
m_wndToolBarSelectCN.SetButtonInfo(1, IDM_SHOW_SELECT_CN_TOOLBAR, TBBS_DROPDOWN, 500);  
m_wndToolBarSelectCN.GetItemRect(1, &rect2);
rect2.bottom = rect2.top + 200;
sg_cbToolsbarNodes.Create(WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|WS_VSCROLL|CBS_DROPDOWN, rect2,
                           &m_wndToolBarSelectCN, IDS_TOOLBAR_SELECT_CB_NODE);
```

Is this something related to the code, am I doing something wrong within these functions? Or is the issue related to the resource files/bitmaps?

Comment: A guess: `m_wndToolBarSelectCN.GetItemRect(3, &rect2);` returns an invalid rect. Can you debug and check what is returned? BTW, Why in first case you used index 0, and in the second case you used index 3?

Comment: Are you sure that you toolbar has this 3 elements?

Comment: The 0 and the 3 are indexes of the buttons in my resource files. Initially there are two buttons 0 and 1 and two combo boxes 2 and 3. For the purpose of this question i omitted the two buttons that works and forgot to change the index of the second combo box. I will edit it now

Comment: As for the GetItemRect it returns a bounding rectangle at the index provided. I did not give it a size, if I'm not mistaking it should fill the space provided for it on the toolbar by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. I simply needed spacers between my comboboxes. The first one was showing fine because there was nothing to its left. The second one's textbox was being covered (overlapped) by the first one.